# ¿Subir Web Service .NET ASMX a CPanel es posible?

Tags: asp.net, webservice, cpanel

buenas tardes, soy nuevo en la creación de Web Services, por lo que me surge una inquietud sobre si es posible subir mi asmx a mi hosting administrado con CPanel o requiero de un servidor con IIS de manera obligatoria?

Answer (score 1):

Los hosting con CPANEL son en LINUX sin soporte para ASP.NET

Yo tengo con el mismo provedor un hosting en LINUX con CPANEL y otro en Windows/IIS con PLESK, en este ultimo es donde publico Web services y aplicaciones ASP.NET